# undefined variable related to session/cookie

Tags: php

I have a log in form that allows persistent login and regular session. Long story made short, when users are in their account, they can change password, email and stuff. But for that, I need to get their username from their session or cookie first (so I can do the proper SQL query).

I try to do so with this code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
else
if(isset($_COOKIE['username']))
{
    $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
}
```

But if I try to echo $username, I keep getting "undefined variable". **Why is that?**

I noticed that if I put a session_start(); at the top. I get the proper username for session but not for cookie of course. **How can I solve that?**

The weird part (for me) is that I got the exact same code (well that part) in another page and username isn't undefined.

PS: If something isn't clear or more information is needed, please tell me.

**EDIT**

I tried this:

```
    function accountValidation()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    }

    else if(isset($_COOKIE['username']))
    {   
        $cookie = $_COOKIE['username'];
        $explode = explode(' - ', $cookie);
        $username = $explode['0'];
    }
         echo $username;
}

accountValidation();
```

And it worked ... So if I put it into a function and then call it, it works?! What is the diference? Why does it need to be into a function for it to work???

Comment: It's important to know how to debug your code. Use `var_dump($_COOKIE);` and `var_dump($_SESSION);`.

Comment: Another thing - how do you set cookies. Are you using `setcookie()` function?

Comment: You should have a final `else` branch setting `$username = NULL;` or something like that, just for the case that it is available neither as cookie nor as part of the session.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use a cookie for this. Users can easily change their cookies.

Comment: @barmar, the cookie has a random token stock into it, that token is also saved in the db. If they change any value on the cookie, an error is displayed and they can't even log in.

Answer (score 1):

If you set certain cookie, it would be available to you from next reload. As $_COOKIE is set when a page head is called. You wont be able to retrieve the cookie from the same page which has set the cookie. I hope you got what i meant. If not let me know I would give an better example.

### EDIT:

Example

```
<?php
    session_start();  
    $_SESSION['test'] = 'test1success';  
    echo $_SESSION['test'];// would display test1success  
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['test2']))  
    {
        setcookie("test2", "test2success", time()+3600);
    }  
    echo $_COOKIE['test2'];  
    // wont display test2success when you load the page for first time
    // reload it & it would display test2success
?>
```

**Explanation:**
The first thing you need to understand is that the cookie is stored on your PC(browser) when the page is loaded.  The client (i.e. browser) sends cookie headers to the server & does the page execution. The values set by set_cookie during page execution are set on the client pc, and the server doesn't know about the new values just set - unless you reload the page & the cookie header is sent back.

Comment: Not really xD. Appreciated if you could explain a little bet more. And that's for the cookie, the same applies to the session?

Comment: Ah ok I get it =). I think that doesn't apply here, the cookie is set one page before (in the log in page) then the user go to the account page, which (re)load the cookie just set. I may be wrong tho. What do you think?

Comment: correct once the cookie is set by login page, if user moves on to account page then he can access the set cookie stored by login page.